# How to run ant script where ant is not installed?

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant script which compiles java code and executes it but when I run it on a machine where ant is not installed it does not execute nor compile. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `ant` doesnt need any installation, just copy the `ant` bin and its related `jars`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do this.

Basically, running a program require having this program installed. No mater what program it is.

Comment: It doesn't have an installer per se like Java has.  As @SajanChandran pointed out in the above comment, it's just some jar files and scripts anyway.  Installation is as simple as unzipping the files.  Updating the environment variables is only a convenience.

Comment: No matter how easy it is to install, you still need to install it.

Comment: Agreed.  My point was that there is not an installer.  It's not clear to me if that is his issue or not.  FYI, you got my upvote because indeed you are correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy *bin* and *lib* directories from a Ant -package to your project path and run "bin\ant".

Or for example you project path could contain:

- build.xml
- src
- software\ant\bin
- software\ant\lib

You can run "software\ant\bin\ant" in you project path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create something similar to the [gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) for ant.

Basically, it's a batch/shell script and a simple jar that only need a valid JAVA_HOME to run. When you launch this script it download gradle if required (i.e. not already available at a well known location), then it execute your gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine someone saying, *"I have a C/Python/Perl/C++/Whatever program I want to compile. Is there anyway to compile that C/Python/Perl/C++/Whatever program without having to install C/Python/Perl/C++/Whatever?"*

The answer would pretty much be no. You need Ant to interpret the Ant build files.

Fortunately, installing Ant is pretty straight forward. You download the ZIP file from [Ant's Distribution Page](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), then unzip it into some directory (preferably one without spaces in the name. `C:\Program Files\Apache Ant` isn't a good choice, but `C:\apache-ant` would be fine.

Now, you set two environment variables, `ANT_HOME` pointing to where you installed Ant, and `JAVA_HOME` pointing where you installed the Java JDK. (Windows comes with the Javaruntime, but you need to have the Java JDK which you can get from Oracle.) This can be done by going into the System Control Panel->Advanced

> ***WARNING***: When installing Java Developer Kit (JDK), be very, very careful not to accidentally install the *Ask Toolbar*. Java does this by default.

Once that is done, set your PATH (again via the PATH Environment variable to include `%ANT_HOME/bin` and `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` at the beginning of your path.

Then, running `ant` on the command line in a Console window will run Ant. The whole procedure takes about 10 minutes to do.